# Composer autoload not loading class in Silex

Tags: php, autoload, silex

I've got a situation using composer to load a class in a Silex app.

This class is located at:

```
src/custom/UserProvider.php
```

In my composer.json, I've added this lines:

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-0": {
        "CustomNamespace": "src/custom/"
    }
}
```

Inside my UserProvider.php file, I've got:

```
namespace CustomNamespace;
```

When I ran *composer update* in console, this line was added to the /vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php

```
'CustomNamespace' => $baseDir . '/src/custom/',
```

But, when I try to use the class:

```
new CustomNamespace\UserProvider();
```

I got this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'CustomNamespace\UserProvider' not found in /home/ubuntu/www/project/web/index.php on line 27

Does anyone knows what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Is the file called src/custom/CustomNamespace/UserProvider.php?

Comment: hm... I'm going to try this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is exactly what @Maerlyn said in his comment.

Everthing works fine when I moved my file to **src/custom/CustomNamespace/UserProvider.php**

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add a note here if someone comes across my issue, which displayed itself the same as this question, but had to do with case sensitivity.

I moved my site from OS X (not case sensitive) to Ubuntu (case sensitive), which complained that the class did not exist. The file was named myclass.php, and when I renamed it to MyClass.php it worked.

Comment: Good to know, @Hans Nilsson! Thx for complementing my question :)